# remove project explorer from eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, project-explorer

I'm writing an Eclipse plugin and seem to have many issues with users using the plugin with the **Project Explorer**.

1. Is there a way to remove the Project Explorer from Eclipse so users won't be able to use it (not only hide it)? I provide the users with the Eclipse package so I can edit it and only then send it out.
2. Why is Project Explorer behaving so differntly than Package Explorer/Navigator?

Example of issues:

- Double clicking on a file in the Project Explorer doesn't always open it. Right clicking on the file and choosing the Open option - works. F3 works as well. this issue seems related to the Eclipse bug https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=131326
- My plugin has a tool bar that I set to be seen only when a project of my type is in focus. it works perfectly in Package and Navigator Explorers, but in Project Explorer, if a user points to a sub folder of the project, it is not recognized as my plugin's project and the tool bar does not appear.

Thanks!

Comment: You will have to explain what you have seen before anyone can answer point 2. What do you think project explorer does differently from the other views?

Comment: What "issues" are you running into? You shouldn't stipulate that something that's in every build of Eclipse be removed just for the sake of your package.

Comment: added example of issues in the question, thansks.